# How to access image via URL in Sailsjs --no-frontend API

Tags: node.js, static, upload, sails.js, image-upload

I have an API project with Sailsjs, this was created with option **--no-frontend**.

So, i have an action that make an image upload to a folder named "uploads" in root directory, images are uploaded with success and i can see them in this folder, everything's ok till now.

When i try to access this image from another application via URL like:

**http://localhost:1337/uploads/image_name.jpg**

I got 404. My question is: How can i access my uploaded images via URL in my custom folder **uploads**?

Answer (score 3):

I have one technique that I prefer and it's pretty simple.

Inside .sailsrc add paths config like this:

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "paths": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}
```

Add folder to root of your app called public and inside add uploads folder like this:

[image: Folder structure]

After this, just lift your app and test.jpg will be available on localhost:1337/uploads/test.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I end up serving images with Nginx block, like this:

```
server {
         server_name myapi.dev;
         location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
            root   /var/www/myapi/uploads/;
         }
}
```

So, i can access images via URL:

**http://myapi.dev/279b68b9-ae43-4674-a85d-94d5bad3365a.png**